# Where should I post a question about googlevideo.com and streaming sites?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I asked the question linked below on two sites so far, Stack Overflow and Super User. Both deleted it and referred me to the other site. I read the thing for both sites, and it seemed like it was within scope of either, but I guess not. Where would you guys recommend posting it?

*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38273368/how-do-most-video-streaming-websites-use-googlevideo-com-to-host-their-pirated*

Comment: You question has a lot of clutter to it. Try narrowing it down to a single, clear question. Stack Exchange is not a "forum" for discussion, it's a Q&A site with specific questions and answers.

Comment: Stack Exchange & Super User are focussed Q&A sites, not forums.  Both put your question On Hold pending improvement, neither deleted it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where should I ask questions about programming without a \_real\_ problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183440/where-should-i-ask-questions-about-programming-without-a-real-problem)

Answer (score 1):

There's probably not a good place in Stack Exchange for your question.

The most likely place is *probably* [Web Apps](http://webapps.stackexchange.com), but I suspect your question, as written, would fare just about as well there as it has elsewhere. Web Apps is more for power user questions about web applications; a question on how pirates keep their content online doesn't seem to be a good fit.

Comment: Well the reason I initially became interested is because a documentary my mom made is being shared by pirates like this, and I was going to send a notice to google which led me down this rabbit hole. I appreciate the response however, it's the first one I've gotten on stackexchange